# Word2Vec Implementation

Tags: nlp, word2vec

In word2vec why is the implementation of likelihood function multiplication of probabilities of finding a neighbouring word given a word? I didnt get why the probabilities should be multiplied.Is there a reason/intuition behind it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "probabilities of finding a neighboring word given a word"

here you refer to the Skip-Gram architecture, where given the center word you predict the surrounding words.

This extract from these [notes](https://cs224d.stanford.edu/lecture_notes/notes1.pdf) might clarify your question.   Note that by assuming the conditional independence the total probability factors into a product.

> "As in CBOW, we need to generate an objective function for us to evaluate the model. A key difference here is that we invoke a Naive Bayes assumption to break out the probabilities. If you have not
>   seen this before, then simply put, it is a strong (naive) conditional independence assumption. In other words, given the center word, all output words are completely independent."

Maybe this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.3722.pdf) can also help, though it is about negative sampling it is a very clear exposition.